# Hadoop 2.2 - Combine Reducer Output

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

My Map/Reduce job outputs lines of the form

```
Key1 5
Key2 8
Key3 4
Key1 7
Key3 3
```

And I would like to aggregate these results to get the sum of the values by key.
So something like:

```
Key1 12 (5 + 7)
Key2 8
Key3 7 (4 + 3)
```

The naive way would be to simply chain another Map/Reduce job behind the first one but it is inefficient because you have twice more I/O than necessary, the overhead, etc. So I would like to avoid this solution.

The best way to do it would probably be something like `map -> reduce1 -> reduce2` where the output of reduce1 is the input of reduce2. Unfortunately, it appears to be impossible to do (see [Chaining Multi-Reducers in a Hadoop MapReduce job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870675/chaining-multi-reducers-in-a-hadoop-mapreduce-job) for example).
I have also looked at [ChainReducer](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/chain/ChainReducer.html) but it doesn't help either since it doesn't allow several reduce steps.

So how would you go about it? Is there something new in Hadoop 2.X that I could use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to to use multiple reducers without mapper. I would suggest you should try to combine both map-reduces logic in a single map-reduce job, if possible. Otherwise identity mapper would be only solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write a reducer job also.But i haven't tried yet.You can give a try.

And you can also write an identity map only job for this, without specifying

```
job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
```

Why because
while writing a Map only job with setting `job.setNumReduceTasks(0);` the output will be in multipe file(output file depends on no of map).

If we are not specifying `job.setNumReduceTasks(0);` an identity reducer will run by default even though we are not writing a Reducer. And the results get stored in a single `part-r-00000` file