# Mapreduce how to chain Mapper >> Reducer >> Reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I have a problem where I need to chain

Mapper >> Reducer >> Reducer

This is my data:

**Dpt.csv**

EmpNo1,DeptNo1
EmpNo2,DeptNo2
EmpNo3,DeptNo1
EmpNo4,DeptNo2
EmpNo5,DeptNo2
EmpNo6,DeptNo1

**Emp.csv**

EmpNo1,10000
EmpNo2,4675432
EmpNo3,76568658
EmpNo4,241423
EmpNo5,75756
EmpNo6,9796854

And finally I want something like this:

Dept1  >> Total_Salary_Dept_1

One major issue is my first reducer is not getting called when I use multiple files as input.

The second issue is that I can't pass that output to next reducer. (ChainReducer can't chain 2 reducers)

I was using [this](https://netjs.blogspot.com/2018/07/chaining-mapreduce-job-in-hadoop.html) as a reference but quickly realized it won't help.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870675/chaining-multi-reducers-in-a-hadoop-mapreduce-job) link where, in one of the comments the author says this: ***"In Hadoop 2.X series, internally you can chain mappers before reducer with ChainMapper and chain Mappers after reducer with ChainReducer."***

Does this mean I will have a structure like this:

Chain Mapper(mapper 1) --> Chain Reducer(reducer 1) --> ChainMapper(unnecessary mapper) --> Chain Reducer(rreducer 2)

And if this is the case then how exactly is the data handed off from Reducer 1 to Mapper 2?

Can someone help me out?

This is my code so far.

Thanks.

```
package Aggregate;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.chain.ChainMapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.chain.ChainReducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.InverseMapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class Sales extends Configured implements Tool{

    public static class CollectionMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>{


        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) 
                 throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            String[] vals = value.toString().split(",");                        
            context.write(new Text(vals[0]), new Text(vals[1]));

         }
    }

    public static class DeptSalaryJoiner extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>{

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) 
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            ArrayList<String> DeptSal = new ArrayList<>();

            for (Text val : values) {

                DeptSal.add(val.toString());

            }      
            context.write(new Text(DeptSal.get(0)), new Text(DeptSal.get(1)));
        }
    }

    public static class SalaryAggregator extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) 
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            Integer totalSal = 0;
            for (Text val : values) {
                Integer salary = new Integer(val.toString());
                totalSal += salary; 

            }      
            context.write(key, new IntWritable(totalSal));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int exitFlag = ToolRunner.run(new Sales(), args);
        System.exit(exitFlag);
    }

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String input1 = "./emp.csv";
        String input2 = "./dept.csv";
        String output = "./DeptAggregate";

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Sales");
        job.setJarByClass(getClass());

        Configuration mapConf = new Configuration(false);
        ChainMapper.addMapper(job, CollectionMapper.class, LongWritable.class, Text.class, Text.class, Text.class,  mapConf);

        Configuration reduce1Conf = new Configuration(false);
        ChainReducer.setReducer(job, DeptSalaryJoiner.class, Text.class, Text.class, Text.class, Text.class, reduce1Conf);

        Configuration reduce2Conf = new Configuration(false);
        ChainReducer.setReducer(job, SalaryAggregator.class, Text.class, Text.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class, reduce2Conf);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(input1));
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(input2));

        try {
            File f = new File(output);
            FileUtils.forceDelete(f);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(output));

        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you tied to MapReduce? Spark would be much easier for something like this.

Comment: Yes, I kinda am! This is a college assignment so...

Comment: so your mapper processes both types of files and emits <empNo, salary> and <empNo, deptNo>. for your 1st reducer, the key is "empNo". your 1st reducer should check the values for being a salary or deptNo. In fact, due to specifics of your problem, the 1st reducer is going to receive exactly two values for every key: one deptNo and one salary. so your 1st reducer emits those two values as a pair <deptNo, salary>. for your 2nd reducer, the key is "deptNo" so it groups all salaries for every deptNo and outputs it

Comment: 2nd mapper basically emits the output of 1st reducer without any additional modifications. so you just need to create two mapreduce jobs, assign 1st mapper and 1st reducer to job1, assign 2nd mapper and 2nd reducer to job2, set output path of job1 as input path of job2 and run job1 and job2 sequentially

Comment: I know that method. But I kinda wanted to avoid having the first output even written to the disk. Directly wanted to pass it in to second reducer. What's the benefit of ChainMapper and ChainReducer if it can't achieve this!